# Using "moved" values in a function

Tags: sorting, rust

I want to learn Rust and am making a small program to deal with sound ques. I have a function with this signature:

```
fn edit_show(mut show: &mut Vec<Que>) {
    show.sort_by(|a, b| que_ordering(&a.id, &b.id));
    loop {
        println!("Current ques");
        for l in show {
            println!("{}", que_to_line(&l));
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error:

> use of moved value: 'show'

I cannot find anything on how to fix this. This seems like an odd error for sort since (I assume) if I was to do this in the main function where I pass in the value which seems quite useless.

Comment: A *queue* is ["a line of people who are waiting for something"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/queue), a *cue* is a ["a signal \[...\] to a performer to begin"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cue). *Que* is not a word AFAIK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

Your problem is in this line:

```
for l in show {
    ...
}
```

This consumes the vector `show`. If you want to just borrow it's elements, you should write:

```
for l in &show {
    ...
}
```

If you want to borrow them mutably, write `for l in &mut show`.

### Explanation

The Rust for loop expects a type that implements [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html). First thing to note: `IntoIterator` is implemented for every `Iterator`. See:

```
impl<I> IntoIterator for I where I: Iterator
```

Now lets search for the `Vec` impls:

```
impl<T> IntoIterator for Vec<T> {
    type Item = T
    ...
}

impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a Vec<T> {
    type Item = &'a T
    ...
}

impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a mut Vec<T> {
    type Item = &'a mut T
    ...
}
```

Here you can see that it's implemented for the `Vec` directly, but also for references to it. I hope these three impl blocks speak for themselves.

Comment: It's worth noting that in some situations `&mut T` will get auto-reborrowed, and so not count as a move. Knowing which is which seems to be a bit of a dark art.

Comment: It seems that in my case the answer was to make it show.iter() instead as doing &show cased a type conflict

Comment: @SebastianMalton are you sure? `&show` and `show.iter()` should be doing the exact same thing in your situation...

Comment: Yup, I can post the compiler log later